# Need marked to *not* convert quotemarks to `&qout;`

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown

I have double quotes in a markdown document that I am parsing to HTML using [*marked*](https://github.com/chjj/marked). I need them to remain unchanged through the parses because I am piping the output through another program that needs them. However, *marked* will automatically. convert my quotes from `"` to `&qout;`.

Is there any way I can make *marked* stop this behavior? Are there any options I can use? Or does anyone know of any other *node.js* markdown parsers that have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`marked` has a setting `sanitize`.  If you set it to `false` (which it is by default), it will leave `"` alone.  This will also not escape `<`, `>`, `&`, or `'` which you may want though.  All this does is replace `"` with `&quot;`, so you can just take the output and call `.replace(/&quot;/g, '"')`

Comment: `sanitize: false` allows you to insert html tags without escaping. So `<span class="foo">` remains unchanged, but `"foo" < "bar"` is converted to `&quot;foo&quot; &lt; &quot;bar&quot;`.

I ended up using a version of your second suggestion though. Using a more precise `.replace`-rule in case I really wanted `&quot;` elsewhere in the document.